# DJANGO: Query for select_related with foreignkey-chain

Tags: django, select

In my project with this ERM:
[image: ERM of my project]

I need to add equipment to an institute.
Tried this:

```
class EquipmentinLocationAdd(CreateView):
   model = EquipmentInstitute, Lot
   form_class = EquipmentInstituteForm
   template_name = 'Procure/equipmentininstitute_add.html'
   def get_success_url(self):
       return reverse('equipmentinstitute_sys', kwargs={'pk':self.object.Institute_id})
   def get_initial(self):
       qs = Institute.objects.get( id = self.kwargs['pk'] )
       initial = {'Institute': qs}
       return initial
   def get_context_data(self, **kwargs): 
       # query for Institute
       Var1 = Institute.objects.all().get( id = self.kwargs['pk'] ) 
       # query for Project
       Var4 = Project.objects.get(id = 5)  # Here is my problem
       context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
       context ['queryset2'] = Lot.objects.all().values_list("LotTitle","Project")
       context.update({'LOK': Var1, 'LOKID': Var1.id, 'PR_id':Var4.id, 'PR':Var4})
       return context
```

Var1 is delivering data of the related institute. 
Var4 is supposed to get the related project. For testing purposes I worked with an fix 'id' of 5

However I need the related project of the selected institute but all my query efforts failed to retrieve the related project_id. (See Var4 in code)

Need help!

Thanks in advance

Ben